# How to read only the value part from JSON Object having nested arrays in JAVA

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have found ways to get specific Key values from JSON object in JAVA. But now for a specific URL, need to find a way to get all the values. This is basically to do a search on this resulting array. Please let me know the way to do this. 
Note: I am new to Jackson API, tried using it, but couldn't succeed.

Here is the sample response JSON response for the URL:

```
"content": [{
        "id": 1068,
        "name": "A",
        "place": []
    }, {
        "id": 1284,
        "name": "B",
        "Breed": "Pug",
        "place": [{
                "pincode": 1469,
                "City": "Bangalore",
                "Owner": [{
                        "name": "John",
                        "Family": {
                            "Son": {
                                "id": 215,
                                "Age": 18
                            },
                            "Daughter": {
                                "id": 558,
                                "Age": 20
                            }
                        }
                }]
        }]
}]
```

To be specific, I want the following output:
1068
A
1284
B
Pug
1469
Bangalore
John
215
18
558
20

Comment: Please provide valid json

Comment: Every request response will be same like if family have 2 sons, 1 daughter then/

Comment: @ScaryWombat Irrespective of what json format I have given, my question is simple: Get only the value part, including the ones present in the nested array within. The duplicate answer you gave outputs only the Values from outer Key values, and not the key values from nested array. So Please remove the duplicate marking for this answer.

Comment: The answer gives the idea how to get the keys - and therefore the values for the keys for any arbitrary bit of JSON - If you have provided **real** JSON, maybe I could have tweaked the answer a bit to help.  Ene if I remove the duplicate, unless you provide something real, I doubt you will get much help - but hey, go for it. I imagine you will get severly voted down (and to close) for not showing any effort what so ever

Answer (score 0):

Let's exercise java.
I changed some keys to lower case ones.

ex) `"Breed": "Pug",` to `"breed": "Pug",`

```
.
├── pom.xml
└── src
    ├── main
    │   └── java
    │       └── com
    │           └── mycompany
    │               └── app
    │                   ├── App.java
    │                   ├── Content.java
    │                   ├── Contents.java
    │                   ├── Owner.java
    │                   ├── Person.java
    │                   └── Place.java
    └── test
        └── java
            └── com
                └── mycompany
                    └── app

11 directories, 7 files
```

You can do it on the root directory.

$ mvn compile exec:java@app

```
---------
Golly... 
---------
1068
A

1284
B
Pug
1469
Bangalore
John
215
18
558
20
---------
Howdy!   
---------
Contents(content=[Content(id=1068, name=A, breed=null, place=[]), Content(id=1284, name=B, breed=Pug, place=[Place(pincode=1469, city=Bangalore, owner=[Owner(name=John, family={Son=Person(id=215, age=18), Daughter=Person(id=558, age=20)})])])])
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Maven Quick Start Archetype</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>app</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <!-- mvn exec:java@app -->
              <mainClass>com.mycompany.app.App</mainClass>
              <arguments/>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.16.16</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

App.java

```
package com.mycompany.app;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.List;

import java.io.IOException;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String json = ""
            + "\"content\": [{"
            + "        \"id\": 1068,"
            + "        \"name\": \"A\","
            + "        \"place\": []"
            + "    }, {"
            + "        \"id\": 1284,"
            + "        \"name\": \"B\","
            + "        \"breed\": \"Pug\","
            + "        \"place\": [{"
            + "                \"pincode\": 1469,"
            + "                \"city\": \"Bangalore\","
            + "                \"owner\": [{"
            + "                        \"name\": \"John\","
            + "                        \"family\": {"
            + "                            \"Son\": {"
            + "                                \"id\": 215,"
            + "                                \"age\": 18"
            + "                            },"
            + "                            \"Daughter\": {"
            + "                                \"id\": 558,"
            + "                                \"age\": 20"
            + "                            }"
            + "                        }"
            + "                }]"
            + "        }]"
            + "}]";

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Contents contents = mapper.readValue("{" + json + "}", Contents.class);

        System.out.println("---------");
        System.out.println("Golly... ");
        System.out.println("---------");

        for (Content con : contents.getContent()) {
            System.out.println(con.getId()    == null ? "" : con.getId()   );
            System.out.println(con.getName()  == null ? "" : con.getName() );
            System.out.println(con.getBreed() == null ? "" : con.getBreed());

            for (Place place : con.getPlace()) {
                System.out.println(place.getPincode() == null ? "" : place.getPincode());
                System.out.println(place.getCity()    == null ? "" : place.getCity()   );

                for (Owner owner : place.getOwner()) {
                    System.out.println(owner.getName() == null ? "" : owner.getName());

                    for (Person p : owner.getFamily().values()) {
                        System.out.println(p.getId()  == null ? "" : p.getId());
                        System.out.println(p.getAge() == null ? "" : p.getAge());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("---------");
        System.out.println("Howdy!   ");
        System.out.println("---------");

        System.out.println(contents.toString());
    }
}
```

Contents.java

```
package com.mycompany.app;

import java.util.List;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Contents {
    private List<Content> content;
}
```

Content.java

```
package com.mycompany.app;

import java.util.List;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Content {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String breed;
    private List<Place> place;
}
```

Place.java

```
package com.mycompany.app;

import java.util.List;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Place {
    private Integer pincode;
    private String city;
    private List<Owner> owner;
}
```

Owner.java

```
package com.mycompany.app;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Owner {
    private String name;
    private Map<String, Person> family;
}
```

Person.java

```
package com.mycompany.app;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Person {
    private Integer id;
    private Integer age;
}
```